# Change screen orientation in a Unity Google Cardboard project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, device-orientation, google-cardboard, sony-xperia

I'm just starting a cardboard project as it's really joyful to experiment VR without any huge hardware, but I have a little problem which sounds really basic : the screen orientation. I just would have my game playable in Landscape Right instead of Left as I'm developing on my Xperia Z.

Usually screen orientation's problems are solved by forcing the orientation through the Player's Settings in the Build Menu. But here, the fact is that when I tick the "Landscape Right" box instead of the left one (which is the default setting of the Cardboard API) it correctly inverts my display but my camera stays at the same orientation as before. 
From this results that my gyroscope works in reverse and that the ground is seen on the top, with all the texts reversed as well.

I've already done what Eldir tried here ([Google cardboard device orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402259/google-cardboard-device-orientation)) but as it wasn't the same problem I'm having, it wasn't efficient.

Do you have any ideas that if the API allows a quick change for this, or if I have to modify the whole parameters of the gyroscope ?

Thanks !

Comment: do you have any answer to this? I am stuck with the same problem now :/

Comment: I tried different things with the build settings such as the landscape rotation, but it appears that the easiest way is to simply turn your device at 180° at the very beginning of your game in order to move your camera.
I set my game as default in landscape left and as my camera is in First Person it doesn't cause any trouble.

How is it for you ?

Comment: yeah I forced it to landscape left now instead allowing it auto rotation.

Comment: And does it works now ?

Comment: well if I force it to landscape left then it is okay. Anyway, I posted a similar question and someone answered me. Though I havent checked it out if it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200052/unity-cardboard-orientation-landscape-right-upside-down