# Wrong orientation using Cardboard SDK on Google Project Tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-project-tango

We use Google Cardboard Unity SDK to make our own game.
(https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity)
But when we run this app on the Google Project Tango.
The screen and the orientation detection seems rotate 90 degrees.
We try a lot of Cardboard apps on the Google Play store and most of them have the same result.
Are there any solution for this situation? Or Google just don't want to take care of Project Tango as well?

Comment: There's a bug when using Cardboard Unity SDK and Tango device together. We are working with the cardboard team to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The Cardboard SDK has a "bug" where it assumes the device is in portrait.  For landscape devices like Tango, this creates the 90 degree rotation.  It will have to be fixed in the SDK, but in the meantime, you can work around the problem using code similar to the following:

[Unity Cardboard Orientation Landscape Right Upside Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200052/unity-cardboard-orientation-landscape-right-upside-down)